# Selenium closes after it opens

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm using Python 3.9.5
Everytime I use the driver.get function, chrome appears for a second and then immediately closes the window. How do I make it like it stays open? It used to work, but when I closed VSCode and re-opened it, I did something that made it so that chrome doesn't appear to be opened.

Comment: did you run code in console/terminal to see error message. And if you want to stop closing at the end of script then you have stop exiting script ath the end - ie. using `input()` at the end, and it will wait for press any key in console to exit script

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this by adding the *detach* option.
For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for more information. Sometimes your web browser has been updated and the chromedriver does not match with the version, so, you have to download the specific version of your browser.